# Feature request: Turn off MathJax's instant rendering without a bookmarklet

Tags: feature-request, mathjax, markdown-preview

I was typing an answer, the moment I inserted some Latex, the input's text would lag behind my typing to an unbearable extent. This was because the website was trying to re-render my input on every keystroke.

Now I recommend this family of websites to various people, I feel uncomfortable recommending it to someone if they must also use bookmarklets to make posting and answering questions bearable.

Comment: The bookmarklet mentioned in this question is probably the one mentioned here: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/10505/feature-request-but-it-woudnt-be-a-feature-itd-be-a-blessing-editing-pane